# Failed when resolving playlist URI in liquidsoap using rss playlist

Tags: xml, rss, icecast, liquidsoap

I've got this an rss xml feed which has mp3's wrapped like this;

```
<enclosure url="http://www.example.com/sites/www.example.com/files/podcast/Dr.mp3" length="48663119" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

I am trying to use this feed as a playlist within Liquidsoap: Here's the code;

```
out = output.icecast(%mp3,host="myhostip",port = myport, password = "mypassword")
out(mount="demo.mp3", 
add([
    out(start=false,mount="novoice.ogg",
    fallback([ playlist("http://www.example.com/feed/21/rss.xml"),
    single("/test.mp3") ]))
    ],
    weights=[3]))
```

But the playlist is not loading. Here are the errors in /var/log/liquidsoap/xml.log

```
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:3] Could not find dynamic module for aacplus encoder.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/gavl.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/faad.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/ao.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/voaacenc.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/oss.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/flac.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/graphics.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/camlimages.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/mad.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/portaudio.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/lo.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/bjack.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/sdl.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/ogg.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/lame.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/ladspa.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/soundtouch.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/pulseaudio.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/samplerate.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/cry.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/gd.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/xmlplaylist.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/vorbis.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/alsa.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/dssi.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/theora.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/lastfm.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/schroedinger.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/taglib.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Loaded plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/flac_ogg.cmxs.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [dynamic.loader:2] Could not load plugin file /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/gstreamer.cmxs: error loading shared library: /usr/lib/liquidsoap/1.0.1/plugins/gstreamer.cmxs: undefined symbol: camlidl_free.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [frame:3] Using 44100Hz audio, 25Hz video, 44100Hz master.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [frame:3] Frame size must be a multiple of 1764 ticks = 1764 audio samples = 1 video samples.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [frame:3] Targetting 'frame.duration': 0.04s = 1764 audio samples = 1764 ticks.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [frame:3] Frames last 0.04s = 1764 audio samples = 1 video samples = 1764 ticks.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [decoder:3] Method "MAD" accepted "/hold/test.mp3".
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [single:3] "/hold/test.mp3" is static, resolving once for all...
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [threads:3] Created thread "generic queue #1".
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [threads:3] Created thread "generic queue #2".
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [threads:3] Created thread "non-blocking queue #1".
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [rss(dot)xml:3] Loading playlist...
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [rss(dot)xml:2] Failed when resolving playlist URI "http://speako.talkosaurus.org/feed/21/rss.xml"!
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [rss(dot)xml:3] Got an empty list: keeping the old one.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [/hold/test(dot)mp3:3] Prepared "/hold/test.mp3" (RID 0).
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [demo(dot)mp3:3] Connecting mount demo.mp3 for source@69.164.219.12...
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [demo(dot)mp3:3] Connection setup was successful.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [threads:3] Created thread "wallclock_main" (1 total).
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [clock.wallclock_main:3] Streaming loop starts, synchronized with wallclock.
2013/07/07 03:24:00 [fallback_5665:3] Switch to /hold/test(dot)mp3.
```

Why isn't the playlist loading?

Answer (score 1):

It was a permissions problem. My xml page was not accessible to anonymous users.